# overflow of large numbers

Tags: arrays, overflow

I have a problem with overflowing.
I mean when I want to calculate factorial or power of large numbers it overflow.
I don't want to use recursion or array.
Is there any other way or Is there any trick?

Answer (score 0):

You can design the algorithm recursive or not. The problem are the data types, if you use a int, it overflows because the int range is from 0 to 65535 cause occupies 4 bytes. You need to use a bigger data type like long or long long.

int x = 0 (4 bytes)
long long y = 0 (8 bytes)

Sorry for my english.

Comment: that was not help full....when i want to multiple two numbers which both are power of ten it overflows.........

Comment: then if you want to multiply this two powers of ten number, maybe, is more efficient sum the exponents and multiply the bases, like: 5*10^25 * 3*10^30 = 15*10^55 .